# How to ensure there is no runaway thread

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

```
import threading
from playsound import playsound
import time

soundList = []
bot_run = True

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        global soundList
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        global soundList
        global bot_run
        while bot_run:
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
                playsound(soundList.pop(0))
            except:
                pass

def main():
    global soundList
    global bot_run
    input()
    soundThread = myThread()
    soundThread.start()
    while not ((user_input := input('sound name: ')) == 'close'):
        soundList.append(user_input)
    bot_run = False

main()
```

I want to ensure someone who clicks the x on cmd doesn't end the program but the thread keeps going.

Does the thread die on its own when the main program ends? Does the bot_run variable cease to exist and therefore exit the while loop?  How can I make sure I don't have this loop running forever when it's no longer being used if the user exited the program without following procedure?

Comment: You can always [`exit`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exit-commands-quit-exit-sys-exit-and-os-_exit/), I guess

Comment: wouldn't that be something the program would call, and thus, not be called if someone did click the x on cmd?